# DD4T - LinkedComponentValues Field count shows zero, even having the LinkLevel attributes

Tags: dd4t, componentpresentation, linking, component

I have a DD4T component template with the following source.

```
<CompoundTemplate xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.3/CompoundTemplate">
  <TemplateInvocation>
    <Template xlink:href="tcm:43-2242-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Generate dynamic component" />
    <TemplateParameters>
      <Parameters xmlns="DD4T.Templates.Schemas.DynamicDeliveryParameters">
        <MergeAction>Replace</MergeAction>
        <LinkLevels xmlns="DD4T.Templates.Schemas.DynamicDeliveryParameters">4</LinkLevels>
        <ResolveWidthAndHeight>yes</ResolveWidthAndHeight>
        <PublishEmptyFields>yes</PublishEmptyFields>
      </Parameters>
    </TemplateParameters>
  </TemplateInvocation>
  <TemplateInvocation>
    <Template xlink:href="tcm:43-2230-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Publish binaries for component" />
    <TemplateParameters>
      <Parameters xmlns="DD4T.Templates.Schemas.DynamicDeliveryParameters">
        <LinkLevels xmlns="DD4T.Templates.Schemas.DynamicDeliveryParameters">4</LinkLevels>
        <ResolveWidthAndHeight>yes</ResolveWidthAndHeight>
        <PublishEmptyFields>yes</PublishEmptyFields>
      </Parameters>
    </TemplateParameters>
  </TemplateInvocation>
</CompoundTemplate>
```

In My page, I have component Which is associated with this component template. In the component I have List of Component (4 component, In turn each component has 5 Fields). 
[image]

but when I run the application, it shows field are 0. 
[image: Visual-Studio-Component-Info]
I have tried publishing unpublished many times. still i am not able to get the solution

Please help me to understand, What i have done wrong, and also is there any guidelines or documents to address such issues/common troubleshooting for DD4T.

Comment: When you preview the published dd4t xml (publish preview in tridion GUI), do you actually see the fields, or not ?

Comment: Can you see the fields in the XML stored in the PAGE_CONTENT table in the Content Delivery database?

Comment: @RobStevenson-Leggett
I have checked the XML in the Page_COntent of DB, it showes empty "<LinkedComponentValues />". Please help me out

Comment: Are you sure you republished the page? Is your Component Template checked out when you published so new link levels are not taken into account?

Comment: @RobStevenson-Leggett
It's not checked out, even i have closed the template in the template builder, then I published the changes. Is it correct ? or do we need to checkout and then publish it.

Comment: No I meant if it was checked out when you published it would have used the previous version. Did the publish definitely succeed?

Comment: You say the linkedcomponentvalues xml element is empty, this does not correspond to what you show in the debug window, which shows the linkedcomponentvalues has four elements. Is your publisher and your website storage config pointing to the same database?

Comment: @HaraldHoffelinck That is correct, But that individual four component does not shows up the fields. See the field count it shows 0.